# Can I count a 2015 expense, if I paid the bill in 2016?

Tags: taxes, tax-deduction, small-business, accounting

I incurred an expense in 2015, put it on a credit card, but didn't pay it off until January 2016, can I count that as an expense for 2015?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You paid the expense when you put it on the credit card in 2015. The fact that you didn't pay the credit card until 2016 doesn't change that.